# SAXBuilder build throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, saxparser

I am parsing this xml

```
<Root><Status>1</Status><Message>Get call Successful</Message><StatusCode></StatusCode><Item type = 'all' subtype = '0' ><subItem><rank>0</rank><name>humywe12</name><value>4500</value></subItem></Item></Root>
```

I am parsing it using this code

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = null;
xml = xml.replaceAll("\t", "");
StringReader r = new StringReader(xml);
try {
    doc = builder.build(r); <-----here it throws error
} catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
return doc;
}
```

builder.build(r) it throws exception StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Am I doing something wrong?

**updated**
ok I have removed only these tags "type = 'all' subtype = '0'" and now it is not giving  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Is there any problem with SAXBUILDER ??

Comment: Silly question - "am I doing something wrong"!  Of course you are!  The machine is always right, and you are always wrong ;-).  Post the stack trace, it might have a clue.

Comment: Funny, I just try this code, and it works... I got a Document [Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <Root/>]] My SAXBuilder and Document are comming from org.jdom.Document and org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

Comment: sometimes there are bugs in JDOM parser too :p

Comment: which version are you using of jdom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was a know JDom bug. See http://www.jdom.org/pipermail/jdom-interest/2000-August/001227.html

You may want to check out one of the latest versions of jdom (as fits within your application).

Answer (score 1):

Someone can try and identify the error for you, but what I would do is to start with very small `xml`, say

```
<Root></Root>
```

and keep adding to it till I get the error and then see what in the data caused the error.

Comment: try double quotes ... `type = "all"`. If the xml document is not created by you it may be extremely difficult to pre-process for this replacement if single quotes can occur elsewhere in the document

Comment: Yeah I have also tried it with " " rather than ' ' but still it throws exception. now I have removed those attributes and its working fine now.

Comment: If it is not quotes then maybe it is the space around the `=`. It may have bugs but I doubt it can't handle attributes at all!

Comment: it is a known bug http://www.jdom.org/pipermail/jdom-interest/2000-August/001227.html

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not allowed between the attribute name and the "=", or between the "=" and the attribute value.

See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Attribute).

Comment: I guess he's using a different parser/version.  When he removes the attributes it works.

Comment: I also tried it without spaces but still it throws exception. I am using a an old version of JDOM, might be that was the reason